# Replacing character with word (translating python code to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python

How do you replace a character with another word in JavaScript using a for loop, without the the built in function string replace? For example, replacing the letter 'i' and 'I' with "eye"? In python, I have

```
def eyeForI(word): 
    increment = ""
    for c in word:
        if c == 'i' or c =='I':
            increment += 'eye'
        else:
            increment += c
    return increment
```

Since JavaScript strings does not have an `in` operator, I am having trouble.

```
var increment = ''
function eyeForI(word) {
    for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) == 'i' || word.charAt(i) = 'I') {
        increment+= 'eye';}
        {else(...)}
    }
}
```

Comment: `or` in JavaScript is used as `||`, also, `+=` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in the more rigidly formated languages (that aren't Ruby or Python) you'll have to pay more attention to semicolons and brace usage.  Your logic wasn't off by much, just check your semanics.

The following code will get the job done:

```
var increment = '';        

function eyeForI(word) {
    for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) == 'i' || word.charAt(i) == 'I') {
            increment= increment + "eye";
            }
        else{
            increment= increment + word.charAt(i);
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Does ++ mean the same thing as += like in python?

Comment: i++ means i+=1 or i=i+1

Comment: Last question, if I wanted to write the mirror of a code, how will I do that? For example, a function named mirror that has a string as a parameter and it prints out the string and the string of it backwords? Like mirror('hello') prints out 'helloolleh'?

Comment: What I have is 

`var c = '';
function wordMirror(word){
 for(var i=0; i<word.length;i++) {c = word.charAt(i) + c;
 document.write(word.charAt(i)+c)
 }
}`

Comment: just run the loop from length of original word to 0,
   `for(var i = word.length; i>=0; i--) {
   increment= increment + word.charAt(i);     
    }`
and append that to the word

Comment: So it will be `for(var i = word.length; i>=0; i--) { increment= increment + word.charAt(i); increment.append(word.charAt(i);document.write(increment)}`?

Comment: `var mirrored = word + increment;` would suffice (after the loop ends) since the reversed word is stored in increment.  In pythonic terms, your code adds the slice word[i:len(word)-1] to the original word for every i from len(word)-1 to 0. Your posted code would output mirrorrrororrorirorim if your input is "mirror".

Comment: Then, it should be like this `var increment = '';
function wordMirror(word){
 for(var i = word.length; i>=0; i--) { 
 increment = word.charAt(i) + increment; 
 document.write(word+increment)
 }
}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65854/discussion-between-symba-and-robben).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `substr`:

```
var increment = '';        
function eyeForI(word) {
    for(var i = 0; i<word.length; i++) {
        mychr = word.substr(i,1);
        if(mychr == 'i' || mychr == 'I') {
            increment= increment + "eye";
            }
        else{
            increment= increment + mychr;
            }       
    }
}
```